# Does washing salad remove E-coli?

Tags: hygiene

I don't generally wash salad unless it looks dirty. It's not that I'm unaware of E-coli and pesticides etc, it's that I don't have any conviction that rinsing them with water will significantly remove such nasty contaminants.

Am I wrong? Is there any hard evidence to support the idea that rinsing salad, without soap or scrubbing, will really render it safe?

Comment: While these aren't strictly *duplicate* questions, I think the answers on them address this question, so I wonder if we can close it as a duplicate anyway. [Does washing vegetables remove nutrients?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/10283/23), [Do fruit/vegetable washes effectively remove pesticides?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5865/do-fruit-vegetable-washes-effectively-remove-pesticides).

Comment: Either for notable claim or answer: http://www.bbc.com/news/health-36823404

Comment: Please clarify what "salad" means, i.e.: those vegetable/fruit/fungi ingredients of a salad in-the-making, or a bagged salad mix, or what?  By the usage of the noun "salad" I'm most familiar with, it's not a "salad" until it's made, (i.e. dressed, tossed, garnished, etc.), just as soup ingredients are not soup until they are correctly prepared, combined, and cooked.

Comment: I mean the raw ingredients -- spinach, carrots, etc. Dressings and arrangements aren't relevant in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed you're wrong.

A study reported that **washing lettuce leaves with tap water for 15 s** provided a log reduction of 1.16 (93.08 %) of the *E. coli* population, while "*prolonging washing time with running tap water to 30 s significantly increased (P < 0.05) this reduction to 2.2 log CFU per leaf*" — **that is, 99.37 %**.

The study also mentions better results on cabbage, lemons and tomatoes (though while "*thoroughly rubbing*" them), and reports that a log reduction of 5.68 (**99.9998 %**) is achieved after **rubbing tomatoes for only 8 s under tap water**.

Reference : [*Reduction of Escherichia coli O157:H7 on Produce by Use of Electrolyzed Water under Simulated Food Service Operation Conditions*](http://jfoodprotection.org/doi/abs/10.4315/0362-028X-72.9.1854) ([open access PDF](http://jfoodprotection.org/doi/pdf/10.4315/0362-028X-72.9.1854)), Pangloli *et al*, Journal of Food Protection, 72, 9, 2009.  (Note that it uses tap water as control, the purpose of the paper being electrolyzed water.)

NB : You asked about *Escherichia coli* specifically, but there are similar reports about other pathogens, e.g. another study found that **simply rinsing (without rubbing) broccoli/lettuce leaves, apples and tomatoes for 15 s** resulted in a removal of *Listeria innocua* (used as a surrogate for *Listeria monocytogenes*) by **96.11 %, 99.02 % and 99.21 %**, respectively (log reduction of 1.41, 2.01 and 2.10).

Reference : [*Efficacy of Home Washing Methods in Controlling Surface
Microbial Contamination on Fresh Produce*](http://jfoodprotection.org/doi/abs/10.4315/0362-028X-69.2.330) ([open access PDF](http://jfoodprotection.org/doi/pdf/10.4315/0362-028X-69.2.330)), Agnes Kilonzo-Nthenge, Fur-Chi Chen, Sandria Godwin, Journal of Food Protection, 69, 2, 2006.